# How to download file from OpenText ECM page using C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient, opentext

I am seeking feedback on how to download any file from ECM (Enterprise Content Management) of [OpenText](https://www.opentext.com/).

Using the following code I can download any file from the web except the ECM site.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URLLocation, UriKind.Absolute), "file102.pdf");
}
```

When using URL of an ECM page then the file gets downloaded but only 2 KB even if the original file size is, for example, > 1 MB, and this 2 KB file is not readable.

I have checked the response header from the ECM URL, giving it below, hoping it will help finding a solution to this problem:

```
Header Name:X-Frame-Options, Header value :SAMEORIGIN

Header Name:Content-Language, Header value :en

Header Name:Content-Length, Header value :1162

Header Name:Content-Type, Header value :text/html;charset=UTF-8

Header Name:Date, Header value :Thu, 26 Sep 2019 19:46:44 GMT

Header Name:P3P, Header value :CP="NON IND UNI COM NAV INT"
```

And here is the response header from a pdf file (non ecm) that is downloaded without having any problem:

```
Header Name:X-SERVER, Header value :bx1,bx01.infobox.ru

Header Name:Age, Header value :10777

Header Name:Connection, Header value :keep-alive

Header Name:Accept-Ranges, Header value :bytes

Header Name:Content-Length, Header value :20597

Header Name:Content-Type, Header value :application/pdf

Header Name:Date, Header value :Thu, 26 Sep 2019 16:48:13 GMT

Header Name:ETag, Header value :"5075-500fc43c07c00"

Header Name:Last-Modified, Header value :Tue, 19 Aug 2014 14:25:52 GMT

Header Name:Server, Header value :nginx/1.12.0

Header Name:Via, Header value :1.1 companyNamecpfp.companyName.com
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? I am having the same issue. thank you.

Comment: Sorry User 123, I didn't get any response on this question.